How does mt4 easyAndFastGui keep multiple Windows active
I have tried to modify the OnOpenDialogBox function in WndEvents.mql. I have modified several parameters here else. The button can be clicked at present, but the event does not take effect
//--- Block the form
m_windows[w].State(true);  // This was originally flase
//--- Zero priorities of the left mouse click for the form elements
int elements_total=CWndContainer::ElementsTotal(w);
for(int e=0;  e<elements_total;  e++)
m_wnd[w].m_elements[e].SetZorders();  // This was originally ResetZorders

